# Selenium — visiting URL with global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

Suppose I have a config.cfg file with the following:

```
[Info]
keyword: Cool Shirt
```

How would I pass `keyword` into a URL, such that

`driver.get("http://www.somewebsite.com/checkout?keyword")`

achieves the same result as

`driver.get("http://www.somewebsite.com/checkout?keyword=Cool+Shirt")`?

Comment: You want this whole line "keyword=Cool+Shirt" in url ?

Comment: String URL=String.format("http://www.somewebsite.com/checkout?%s",keyword); You can try thi code

Comment: @AnkurSingh Effectively, yes. I'd like to automate filling in the keyword field in the given URL; the constraint, however, is that I'd like to do so by using the global variable from the config.cfg file.

Comment: You can read your keyword value from config file "http://www.opencodez.com/java/read-config-file-in-java.htm" using this way and then pass it into string formater to build string as you want

Comment: @AnkurSingh I'm not sure I follow. I tried the first case and got `name 'string' is not defined`.

Comment: @AnkurSingh Nvm, got it to work! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not related to Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your keyword value from config file ["opencodez.com/java/read-config-file-in-java.htm"](http://%22opencodez.com/java/read-config-file-in-java.htm%22); using this way and then pass it into string formater to build string as you want

```
String URL=String.format("somewebsite.com/checkout?%s",keyword);
```